# How to exclude last row in SED range

Tags: sed

I have log file that contains multiple rows for single log output like this:

`DEBUG : <line1>

        <line2>

TRACE : <line11>

    <line12>

    <line13>

DEBUG : <line21>

    <line22>

    <line23>

TRACE : <line31>

    <line32>

ERROR : <line41>

    <line42>

TRACE : <line51>

    <line52>

DEBUG : <line61>

    <line62>`

I have to clean it from TRACE output.

I use

`sed -e "/^TRACE/,/^DEBUG\|^ERROR/d" <log.txt`

... and get

`DEBUG : <line1>

    <line2>

    <line22>

    <line23>

    <line42>

    <line62>`

Sed removes range inclusively and doesn't print DEBUG and ERROR line just after TRACE block.
I tried other way with sed, but didn't find how to remove TRACE blocks only.

Sed is pretty good but maybe I should use another Unix utility... Please, advise.

Comment: Show us what you want as output please. Thanks for using formatting!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do what you want in sed, although this is a situation where I would normally use perl. This uses sed's "hold space" to collect each section of the log file, and prints (or not) the whole section once it sees the start of the next section.

```
sed -n -e '/^\(TRACE\|DEBUG\|ERROR\)/ ! { H ; $!b } ; x ; /^\(DEBUG\|ERROR\)/ p'
```

However, responding to the subject of the question, I don't think it's possible to exclude the last row from the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^TRACE/ { 
                while ( $0 !~ /^DEBUG/ || $0 !~ /^ERROR/ ) { 
                    getline ; 
                    if ( $0 ~ /^DEBUG/ || $0 ~ /^ERROR/ ) { 
                        print $0 ; 
                        next 
                    } 
                } 
              } 
     { print $0 }' FILENAME
```

AWK to the rescue ;-) (Note: it can be pasted to one line.)

Answer (score 0):

This provides a reasonable technique for splitting the input to different places.  It would be nice to use a case, but if you insist on anchoring the string the the beginning of the line, I don't believe that is possible.

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 3>&1
exec 4> /dev/null
exec 5>&1
while read -r line; do
echo $line | grep ^DEBUG >&3 && exec >&3 && continue
echo $line | grep ^TRACE >&4 && exec >&4 && continue
echo $line | grep ^ERROR >&5 && exec >&5 && continue
echo $line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could duplicate your tags, to remove just the first of them:

```
sed -E "s/^((DEBUG)|(ERROR)) : /\1 : \n\1 /" | \
sed "/^TRACE/,/^DEBUG\|^ERROR/d" | sed "s/^</\t</"

DEBUG : 
DEBUG <line1>
      <line2>
DEBUG <line21>
      <line22>
      <line23>
ERROR <line41>
      <line42>
DEBUG <line61>
      <line62>
```

The last sed-command is just for a better readability, and the first line is left as an exercise. :)